# How to choose a productive group of employees?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, bipartite

I have employees and matrix with ranks how are they working with each other with the results from 0 to 10. I have to select groups with two people and give them work. The problem is I don't know how should I choose groups that sum up group works will be the highest.

```
   A  B  C  D
A  -  3  10 3
B  3  -  0  3
C  10 0  -  3 
D  3  3  3  -
```

For the given example, it would be
<A,C>,<B,D> _ 10 + 3 = 13

Comment: 1) What have you tried? 2) Do you always have a total of 4 people to be split into 2 groups of 2 people, or do you have different values for the number of groups and the number of people per group?

Comment: I have an N number of employees and I would like to combine them in a group of two people each one.

Comment: I would like to choose those groups in which the company will work in a better way

Comment: If the number of groups and people per group are very small, you can just bruteforce the problem: list all possible combinations, calculate the score for each combination, and keep the combination with highest score. In the case of 2 groups of 2 people, there are only 3 different combinations up to symmetries, and only 24 combinations if you blindly enumerates all the groups as `(AB)(CD), (AB)(DC), (AC)(BD), (AC)(DB), (AD)(BC), ...`. Those are extremely small numbers!

Comment: How big is the number `N`?

Comment: Yes but I assume that company size could be more than 10000

Comment: Please add those details (groups of 2 people, total of N people, N could be more than 10000) to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to solve the [Maximum Weight Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_weight_matching) problem.

Wikipedia links to a paper and a C++ implementation by Vladimir Kolmogorov: [http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/papers/BLOSSOM5.html](http://pub.ist.ac.at/%7Evnk/papers/BLOSSOM5.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is [maximum weight matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_weight_matching) in a non-bipartite graph. The classical polynomial-time algorithm is the [Blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) due to Jack Edmonds. Integer programming will also work in a pinch.

Answer (score 1):

@David and @Stef thanks for your help.
I solved the problem using Kolmogorov's algorithm.
I used algorithm implementation from the JGraphT library.
In case if someone is interested here is the link to the project.
https://github.com/CGevorg/Employee_Matcher